# Unable to create a scheduled query in BigQuery, but not sure why

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create an on-demand scheduled query in the BigQuery UI, so that I can connect it to a Pub/Sub topic to run when a data import is complete each day, but I'm unable to create the scheduled query.  I get the pop-up requesting permissions, I click allow and the only message I see is "Scheduled Query Error".

I double checked my permissions, I'm the project owner, and the bigquery.admin, and I have all the permissions listed.  I tried using a daily schedule, tried using a table that exists, a table that doesn't exist, tried using a service account, and double checked that I have the transfers enabled, but I always receive the same error message with no details on why it isn't working.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or what I might be able to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you need to create an empty table first with the schema and mention that as table_id. Must be a GCP bug.

Comment: No, you don't need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this generic error message 'Scheduled query error', and it was driving me mad. I checked all permissions and locations etc. I turns out that the 'Time Travel Window' was set to less than 48 hours for the dataset I was trying to write into. Which apparently BigQuery doesn't like.

To fix this I executed this query

ALTER SCHEMA PROJECTNAME.DATASETNAME SET OPTIONS( max_time_travel_hours = 72);

Comment: answer requires some editing